# Referencing js library from static resource or from the hosted server in a visualforce page. Which approach gives better page performance?

Tags: javascript

I am just curious to understand if there is any difference in page performance between referencing a js library from static resource inside of Salesforce or referencing from a hosted server in a Visualforce page (just like this, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js) ? For instance as just given in this article,

[Referencing the Force.com Canvas SDK](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_framework_referencing_sdk.htm)

Any thoughts please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request is being made from the client to a server in both cases, so the question is which server will return the data quickest which is hard to know.

A (theoretical) advantage of using a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) location is that a user's browser may already have a copy of the file cached because of some other web. But given that different web pages are likely to be using different versions of things like jQuery I doubt that this happens very often.

The benefit of serving the file from Salesforce is that then all the content for your application is coming from one hosting company - Salesforce - that hopefully your customer trusts. Using a CDN adds a second hosting company to the mix and so more risk (of a security breach resulting in the content being hacked).

Comment: Also, accidentally using an auto update CDN link can result in code breaks when incompatible changes to an API are introduced.

Comment: @sfdcfox Wasn't aware of such a mechanism - fair point. Some more discussion of why to avoid: [Latest jQuery version on Google's CDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608242/latest-jquery-version-on-googles-cdn).